# Easy way to convert color range to another?

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, image-editing

I would like to convert the purple color in this image:

[image]
to blue such as:

[image]

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? If not, is there an easy way to replicate the same effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate the image in R,G and B channels, and replace the red channel by zeroes, leaving only the G and B channels.

Example in Mathematica:

```
i = Import["http://tinyurl.com/3wqklof"];
ColorCombine@{ImageSubtract[#[[1]], #[[1]]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &@ ColorSeparate@i
```

[image]

**Edit**

Or, If you need an "exact" blue image, separate in the "HSB" color space, replacing all non zero values of the H matrix by 2/3 (blue), leaving the S and B components untouched.

Example:

```
ColorCombine[{Image[2/3 ImageData@ImageAdd[#[[1]], #[[1]]]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &@
              ColorSeparate[i, "HSB"], "HSB"]
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! Thank you for also appending an explanation with code. However, why is the output smaller/degraded as compared to the original input?

Comment: @Alede I used the default Mathematica's output image size. Plain old laziness.